# Comparing keywords from 2 files and replace a value associated with the keyword from one file to another

Tags: awk, tcl

Sorry for not having a clear title. I'll try to explain my question.

I have two files A and B.

The format of **file A** is something like this:

```
set_time 10 temp max 2 min 1 xyzzy
set_time 10 temp max 2 min 1 abcde
set_time 10 temp max 3 min 2 ersfg
set_time 8  temp max 2 min 0 fdfdf
```

**File B** looks like this:

```
xyzzy 7.5
abcde 8.5
ersfg 9.5
fdfdf 9.0
```

Now, what needs to be done is, I have to search for the last column names in **file A** (`xyzzy`, `abcde`, `fdfdf`, etc.) and replace the 2nd column values with those 2nd column values from **file B**.

So, the output should look like:

```
set_time 7.5 temp max 2 min 1 xyzzy
set_time 8.5 temp max 2 min 1 abcde
set_time 9.5 temp max 3 min 2 ersfg
set_time 9.0 temp max 2 min 0 fdfdf
```

Any help is appreciated. This is a part of a TCL flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the second file with the mappings, something like this:

```
set f [open file_B]
set mapping [dict create]
while {[gets $f l]} {
    if {[feof $f]} break
    dict set mapping {*}$l
}
```

Then process the original file by making `set_time` a command that outputs itself, while changing the desired value:

```
proc set_time {num_to_replace temp max maxnum min minnum mapval} {
    puts "set_time [dict get $::mapping $mapval] $temp $max $maxnum $min $minnum $mapval"
}
```

and then just `source` the original data file:

```
source file_A
```

This assumes of course that the two files have no other lines in them that would mess up the processing.

Comment: This is quite a nice way of handling files that look like (boring) Tcl scripts. It mixes well with [safe interpreters](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/safe.htm) but you have to read the file in the parent there and `$slave eval` it.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you will find an `awk` script useful:

```
FNR == NR {
    fileA[$1] = $2
    next
}

{
    for (i in fileA) {
        if (i == $NF) {
            $2 = fileA[i]
            print
        }
    }
}
```

Run like:

```
awk -f script.awk fileB.txt fileA.txt
```

Results:

```
set_time 7.5 temp max 2 min 1 xyzzy
set_time 8.5 temp max 2 min 1 abcde
set_time 9.5 temp max 3 min 2 ersfg
set_time 9.0 temp max 2 min 0 fdfdf
```

Comment: @Birei, thanks -- with my `awk` scripts, I aim to replicate a Birei-like response :-)

Comment: Thank you. It seemed it to me when reading, I noted similarities but it's all ok. I make it just like that to facilitate the reading to the user, so glad to see it in other posts too :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could write a simple script to do this in your language of choice, splitting the strings at the space characters and using arrays (depending on how large the files are).

But if it's a one-off case that you just need done this time, open up Excel and import the files as CSVs delimited by space characters (or whatever is relevant).  Then you can order the rows as needed and copy'n'paste entire columns of values. Add some extra columns between the values containing the spaces, fill them down then save the file off in to plain text.

It may not be pretty but it can be brutally effective for combining simple data sets. Especially for one-off tasks.

Comment: Thanks. This is not a one-off task though. This is actually a part of a bigger TCL flow I'm writing and am currently stuck here.